# JQuery remove li based on ascii contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically adding list items to a ul

```
<ul>
<li>thing 1</li>
<li>thing 2</li>
<li class='colorblock'>thing 3</li>
<li class='colorblock'>thing 4</li>
<li>thing 5</li>
</ul>
```

In some situations I need to enclose a few of the li with the following

```
$('.colorblock:first').before('<li>[&plusmn; </li>');
$('.colorblock:last').append('<li>]</li>');
```

that products the following

```
<ul>
<li>thing 1</li>
<li>thing 2</li>
<li>[± </li>
<li class='colorblock'>thing 3</li>
<li class='colorblock'>thing 4</li>
<li>]</li>
<li>thing 5</li>
</ul>
```

now, if I also may need to remove those two li's with something along the following

```
$('li').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === '[&plusmn; '; }).remove();
$('li').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === '[± '; }).remove();
$('li').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === ']'; }).remove();
```

my problem is that none of these are correctly matching to

```
<li>[± </li>
```

I've ran out of ideas on how to strictly match and remove that li. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an encoding issue with the file it was in, needed to be UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    return txt == '[±' || txt == ']'
}).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2HVwb/)

Comment: No luck with that, the fiddle also doesn't display the 2 li's, the page source is just showing me the "diamond with a question mark in" symbol. the App is only going to be used with chrome which is where the issue seems to be.

Comment: @user1372212 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2HVwb/2/ you need to look at the encoding used for the file

Comment: turns out it was an encoding issue... thanks for the assistance though.